# ASP.NET MVC - Can't locate image file when run with IIS

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I created a HTMLExtension method for a DatePicker.  I reference it from the view as follows (see bolded text for image location):

```
        <label for="Effective Start Date", class="codeValuesEditLabel"> Effective Start Date (YYYY/MM/DD): </label>
    <%= Html.DatePicker("CodeValueNewEditModel_EffectStartDate", "CodeValueNewEditModel.EffectStartDate", "../../Content/images/calendar.gif",
            Model.codeValueNewEditModel.EffectStartDate) %>
```

The HTMLExtension method:

```
public static string DatePicker(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string name, **string imageUrl**, object date)
    {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        // Build our base input element    
        html.Append("<input type=\"text\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + name + "\"");

        // Model Binding Support    
        if (date != null)
        {
            string dateValue = String.Empty;
            if (date is DateTime? && ((DateTime)date) != DateTime.MinValue)
                dateValue = ((DateTime)date).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
            else if (date is DateTime && (DateTime)date != DateTime.MinValue)
                dateValue = ((DateTime)date).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
            else if (date is string)
                dateValue = (string)date;

            html.Append(" value=\"" + dateValue + "\"");
        }

        // We're hard-coding the width here, a better option would be to pass in html attributes and reflect through them    
        // here ( default to 75px width if no style attributes )    
        html.Append(" style=\"width: 75px;\" />");

        // Now we call the datepicker function, passing in our options.  Again, a future enhancement would be to    
        // pass in date options as a list of attributes ( min dates, day/month/year formats, etc. )    

        // If there is no image given, open calendar by clicking on text box
        if (imageUrl == null)
        {
            html.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(document).ready(function() { $('#" + id + "').datepicker( { dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', changeMonth: 'true', changeYear: 'true', duration: 0 }); });");      
        }
        else
        {
            html.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(document).ready(function() { $('#" + id + "').datepicker( { dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', showOn: 'button', changeMonth: 'true', changeYear: 'true', buttonImage: '" + **imageUrl** + "', duration: 0 }); });");
        }
        html.Append("</script>");

        return html.ToString();
    }
```

Everything works when run on the development server but when run with IIS, the image is not found.  Generally I would use "Url.Content" to fix these problems but I can't place that in the Javascript.  Does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Look at the output (view source) for the two different host locations (iis and development).  If that doesn't help you solve your problem, post it here.

Comment: Why can't you use `Url.Content` around the imageUrl parameter when constructing the javascript in your helper?

Comment: I modified the script tag to have:   buttonImage: '<%=Url.Content(\"" + imageUrl + "\")%>'     And modified the view to pass in the following path (imageURL):   "~/Content/images/calendar.gif"   The image is not found on the development server though. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to change:

```
<%= Html.DatePicker("CodeValueNewEditModel_EffectStartDate", "CodeValueNewEditModel.EffectStartDate", "../../Content/images/calendar.gif",             Model.codeValueNewEditModel.EffectStartDate) %>
```

to:

```
<%= Html.DatePicker("CodeValueNewEditModel_EffectStartDate", "CodeValueNewEditModel.EffectStartDate", Url.Content("~/Content/images/calendar.gif"),             Model.codeValueNewEditModel.EffectStartDate) %>
```